# setting document root in Angular 5.6.0 behind Varnish proxy

Tags: angular, varnish, document-root

My Angular 5 application will run behind a varnish proxy. Say our corporate website runs on `test.corporate.com` and my local computer is `dev5.local`, then varnish is now, for the time being, configured by system management to point https://test.corporate.com/albert to http://dev5.local:4200/ (but they can point it to anything we like). This is a proxy, not a redirect. In my angular index.html running with ng-serve, I have configured the documentroot:

```
<base href="/albert/">
```

When I go in my browser to https://test.corporate.com/albert/, the html of my index.html loads, but all other files (css, javascript) fail to load. The same happens when I go to http://dev5.local:4200/, but that the latter doesn't work makes sense because of the documentroot.

We've tried variations of the above varnish config and documentroot, but nothing seems to work. With the config above, which is the variant that makes the most sense to me, it tries and fails to load https://test.corporate.com/albert/inline.bundle.js . I also seem to be unable to manually edit the url and see if I can load that js file in my browser, e.g. https://test.corporate.com/albert/albert/inline.bundle.js also gives a "not found" with a redirect.

As the html does load, it should not be related to http vs https.

Comment: So you see the `base` tag in the served html? If so then you need to make sure the static files are loaded using paths like `static/js/app.js` and not `/static/js/app.js` or `./static/js/app.js`

Comment: I have no experience in Varnish but one of the variations that helped me at some point is make the base href serve files by making the path relative './albert/', and adjusting all the injected files in the index.html to use relative path instead of absolute. This solution might work in production build.

Comment: Sorry, I have mistaken the Angular version, it should be 5.6.0. I don't know if that affects the current comments and answer, but I'm going to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about Varnish Proxy but, I have faced this same issue while deploying my code in apache-tomcat server, and serving the site not from '/' but from '/anotherPath/' in angular 4.

What I did was while building app I have added below 2 attributes in build command

```
ng build --prod --base-href "/" --deployUrl="/anotherPath/"
```

Post this build, I have updated `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/anotherPath/">` in index.html file inside newly created dist folder, and then deployed it to the server.

This was a workaround which resolved my issue.

Once you fix this you might also face another issue i.e. reload will not work, since you will be serving from '/anotherPath/' and not '/'. For eg on reload of
https://test.corporate.com/albert/user/login you will get an error.

For that in apache-tomcat we had rewrite rules configured. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options either go through all of your static files and add their relative paths inside index.html.

OR

You can use a task runner like, [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) with packages like [grunt-injector](https://github.com/klei/grunt-injector), with which you can check for all the static files that you want to use from the project folder and it will automatically add the relative path inside the index.html file.

Comment: The problem is also that I cannot load the static files directly through the browser address. So it seems the static files are not served at all.

Comment: Have you tried accessing one of your static files while removing the base-href from the URL?

Comment: I've tried variations of the url, but removing /albert/ doesn't work as varnish doesn't forward that.

Comment: If you use the URL with base href then the link will always be treated as an angular route instead of a static file path. You need to look for adding a filter in the varnish configuration to for `/albert/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (depending on router configuration):

```
<!--angular routing-->
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write('<base href="' + document.location.href.split('#')[0] + '" />');
</script>
```